# Script only works first time, not after refresh in IE8

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

Hi I have this code in my footer, it workes fine in all Browsers but IE8, in IE8 it worke fine only on direct pageloads, if i enter the domain and hit enter, it works like a charm, but if I hit refresh, I get a "Object Expekted" because " google.maps" becomes a empty object eg: JSON.stringify(google.maps) == '[]'

Any ide what chould be wrong? (if i delete the cache and go to the page directly it still works fine.)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
      jQuery( ".all-map" ).each(function( index ) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery(this).val());
        var allMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(obj.mapId), {
        zoom: obj.zoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.centerLat, obj.centerLong),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        }
        );

        var locations = eval(obj.locations);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
       map: allMap
       }); 
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          jQuery('#'+obj.mapId).parent().siblings().eq(i).click();
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(allMap, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

  });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: I would say IE8 is broken. Is it the same with all versions of IE or only IE8? Have you tried the different compatibility settings in IE? What are the cache settings for the page?

Comment: Does document.getElementById(obj.mapId) exist in the page flow before or after this script? Just thinking that the onload callback might fire before is object exists in the page.

Comment: Same in all comp modes, dont know about the cache settings, but it is a fresh install

The problem seam to be that "google.maps" is null after a refresh

Comment: obj.mapId is a static html object, rendered long before the script is run

Comment: Does IE8's developer console indicate anything useful?

Comment: Nope only that google.maps is '{}' after i hit refresh, that gives me the error Object Expekted later on

Answer (score 0):

It is a race condition.  When the information is already in IE's cache, the google onload event handler is running before the DOM is rendered (the page onload event) and the map object doesn't exist in the DOM, so document.getDocumentById can not find it.  You need to wait for the document to be loaded as well as the google script onload event to fire.

Comment: `jQuery(function(){
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(google.maps));
});
);
`
Still outputs "[]" on reloads but the first time it contains a lot of info.

Do i need to wait ever longer?

Answer (score 0):

I still dont know what was wrong, but i did some restructuring and whent with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.load("maps", "3",  {
        callback: initialize , 
        other_params: "sensor=false"
    });
});
```

and now it works in IE8 as well, thanks 4 the help!